# Save matrix without the initial tab in ascii-file

Tags: matlab, file, ascii

I have a matrix `vtx` that contains XY coordinates and I want to write it into a file that already exists, with some custom headers.

I use the line `save('z2.vtx','vtx','-ascii','-append');` to save the matrix in to the specific file. The problem is that I would like each row NOT to have an initial tab.

Instead of the output:

```
#Some headers
   6.229968e+00    -5.000000e-01
```

I would like

```
#Some headers
6.229968e+00    -5.000000e-01
```

Can this be solved with `save` or `dlmwrite` or do I need to do a loop and use `fwrite` with the custom format?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using [**`dlmwrite`**](http://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/dlmwrite.html) you have a lot of more options for writing simple text files than with `save`, e.g. definition of the delimiter or row and column offsets.

```
dlmwrite('z2.vtx',vtx,'delimiter','\t','precision','%1.2e','-append');
```

Regarding your comment: you're looking for the `'precision'` property of `dlmwrite` and you want to define a [**C-style format string**](http://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sprintf.html#inputarg_formatSpec).

Example: `'%1.2e'` gives you a float with one digit before the dot and two digits after, always using the scientific notation.

Output in text file:

```
4.27e+01    8.85e+01
9.55e+01    8.40e+01
7.24e+01    1.18e+01
5.81e+01    4.10e+01
5.40e+01    1.20e+01
7.05e+01    5.72e+01
...
```

Comment: The thing is, dlmwrite does not write in the format I posted, just writes e.g. `34.5567` instead of `3.45567e+01`. I haven't found the way to change that.

Comment: @AnderBiguri Have a look at my edit, I think it is what you are looking for.

Comment: Fantastic, as usual. Thank you.